# verify if a file exists in dart cloudinary

Tags: flutter, dart, file, upload, cloudinary

I have some difficulties finding if an image/video exists in my Cloudinary media.

I'm using Dart (cli project) and the documentation recommended packages: cloudinary_api, cloudinary_url_gen

the following code works with the publicId but not with the image name.

```dart
 static bool imageExists({String publicId = ''}) {
    try {
      if (!_isInitialized) {
        init();
      }

        // TODO: figure out a way to get the image by its name instead.
        final CldImage cldImage = cloudinary.image(publicId);

        print(cldImage);

      // cldImage.
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

I have implemented a singleton class you can find the whole implementation here:

https://gist.github.com/callmephil/1f1fdcff2ec6ffcf5cc8bdc54027b6a4

I have a constraint where I can't directly store the image publicId and there's very little documentation within the lib, and the official Cloudinary Documentation for dart is quite outdated as well. this complicates the task a lot...

Comment: can you clarify what you mean when you say it works with publicId but not image name? Can you send some examples and the error you receive?

Comment: I need to see if a file exists in my cloudinary storage. But I don't always have its publicId, So I need to look it up from its name instead to prevent re-uploading the same file. It doesn't look like it's an available feature at the moment, My workaround is to scrape my dashboard, get a json of available files, and validate my uploads.

Comment: You can instead pass the `overwrite=false` parameter with your upload request as per https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_optional_parameters. By default it's true but when set to false, a response is returned immediately if an asset with the same Public ID was found.